# Paperclip gem spoofing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using CentOS. I have paperclip gem newest version. I have read about spoofing and yet problem still persists! I even tried older version 3.5.2 and still getting error. I am doing this on remote server! Dont know if I have to restart apache or something?
Heelp!

```
I, [2014-04-09T18:41:45.251093 #5841]  INFO -- : Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/5b42e9da0503617fea7f216d7860262920140409-5841-k6wzm6'
I, [2014-04-09T18:41:45.257581 #5841]  INFO -- : [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename justdoit.jpeg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

After adding Options , Now I am getting this:

```
I, [2014-04-09T21:20:46.797630 #11118]  INFO -- : Started GET "/system/bboys/avatars/000/000/001/medium/Casper_Family_11.jpg?1397064045" for 90.197.101.127 at 2014-04-09 21:20:46 +0400
F, [2014-04-09T21:20:46.799580 #11118] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/bboys/avatars/000/000/001/medium/Casper_Family_11.jpg"):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

Comment: Go to your terminal and run `file -b --mime path/to/file/justdoit.jpeg` and share the results.

Comment: Could you make a new question with this new problem please - it keeps it easier for others to find problems and solutions in the future.  When you post the new question please your model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't worried about the spoofing check for jpeg/jpg files you can set the Paperclip option:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = { jpeg: 'image/jpeg', jpg: 'image/jpeg' }
```

This will bypass the `file -b --mime-type` command.

Comment: where do I set this option? Thank you! In model?

Comment: You can set it anywhere that is read when the application intialises; `config/application.rb`, `config/environments/<environment>.rb` if you want to be environment specific.  I created `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` for things like this because it's not environment specific and I like to separate out gem configuration from my application.

Comment: @ Graeme McLean @ Kirti Thorat I thought it was fixed but now getting new error. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I didnt have installed [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and it is a requirement for paperclip to work.